# How to open to a certain page on a PDF document from a link?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf

I'm trying to open a PDF document from a hyperlink to a certain page. So I set the link to this: `http://www.mywebsite.com/document.pdf#Page=14`

However, when I click the link initally that's the url I see in the urlbar, but it eventually goes to just: `http://www.mywebsite.com/document.pdf`

I can type the `#Page=14` to the end and press enter and it will work but for some reason it will not work the first way.

What am I doing wrong or what might be preventing me from opening to the correct page? Thanks!

Comment: That *should* work.  Out of curiosity, have you tried it in lower case?  In other words #page=14 instead of #Page=14?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little confused by this syntax. The bookmark in a URL will be the name of an anchor tag. Something like `#topic1`, `#topic2`. What is the purpose of having a name/value pair as your bookmark?

Comment: The purpose is to open the PDF directly at a particular page, rather than at the first page.

Comment: @MarkJ: Yes, that part was obvious. The less obvious part for me was how `#name=value` is part of a valid URL.

Comment: It's the way Adobe has it set up I suppose. So it's not a bookmark or anything I've set up, but just the page number of the PDF; http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/317/317300.html

Answer (score 0):

It should work [according](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/317/317300.html) to Adobe.

Unless you are using Acrobat 7.0 in Internet Explorer. There was a [bug](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/326/326332.html) with that combination. Solution: upgrade to Acrobat Reader 8, or use a different browser.

Comment: I'm using Adobe Reader 9.3.1. So I don't think that's the problem.  I also tried it in Chrome and IE9 and both have the same result.